# ReactJS problem when calling function inside .map at jsx block code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call to an arrow function inside jsx statement while using .map() js function:

```
      <ul className="list-group col-10 ms-5">
        {datoPaises.map((item) => (
          <li className="list-group-item" key={item.id}>
            {this.parseRegions(item)}
            <span> Muertes nuevas: {item.today_new_deaths} </span>
            <span>Muertes totales: {item.today_deaths}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

this.parseRegions(item) is returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseRegions' of undefined

which is not happening when just writing the item inside the jsx block

```
      <ul className="list-group col-10 ms-5">
        {datoPaises.map((item) => (
          <li className="list-group-item" key={item.id}>
            {item.id}
            <span> Muertes nuevas: {item.today_new_deaths} </span>
            <span>Muertes totales: {item.today_deaths}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

this one display all data correctly, the problem appears when trying to use the function.

Comment: Did you read the error? Where do you define `parseRegions`?

Comment: Is this actually a class-based component? What is `this`? Give a [mre].

Comment: The function is defined in other class, when having it inside the component scope it works fine

Comment: The error says that you want to access a property called parseRegions of a thing (object) called 'this'. But the 'this' you mention is undefined. 
What do you expect the contents of 'this' is?

Comment: bad design, just create a component, pass the props you need to it and render it through the map, that way this wouldn't even happen. Rule of thumb - You want to render something? Use a component not a function within a component.

Comment: @JulianKleine So i should make a new component with the logic  i have inside the map which will be render in each .map iteration?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea :-)